# Data flow not able to capture the row changes from the source .csv azure

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory, dataflow

My idea is to take the csv file as a source & synapse table as a sink using upsert.
whenever I am changing the rows of csv file in data flow source preview it is showing old data.

[image]

This is my source preview
[image]

This is my source file I changed the last indicator to FALSE and uploaded it to blob.
[image]

Again I ran preview for source still indicator is reference to old data
[image]

My source setting
[image]

Dataset setting -
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are changing the source data while in the same continuous data flow debug session, then the source data is being cached in Spark data frames. You will need to invalidate the cache. You can do this by changing the name of your source transformation. That will force ADF to re-read the source data. Change change the name "source1" to "source" before you hit "refresh" in data preview.

Comment: Hi Mark As part of automation my source file is changing every 10 mins do I need to change always name of source. I am just changing the same automation.csv in source. what if I have a every 30 mins trigger of that flow ?

Comment: The caching you are seeing is only in data preview during your active debug session. When you execute this from a pipeline, the data will be dynamic, so won't need to do this trick to invalidate the cache.

Comment: Hi Mark Exe from the pipline i.e you are refring to trigger the pipline then this issue won't persist. I am working in a feature branch so only debug I can do . I tried to put dataflow in pipline and exec it but issue remains same.